# How to std::bind() to create a data member?

Tags: c++, c++11, member, stdbind

I'm generating random values with C++11 nice new generators and distributions. In a function it works like a charm and looks like this:

```
void foo() {
   mt19937 generator;
   uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution;
   auto dice = bind(distribution, generator);
   // dice() will now give a random unsigned value
}
```

But how can I put all three objects in a class as data members?  I can simply write `generator` and `distribution` as data members, but how do I make `dice` a data member without knowing (or wanting to know) its exact type?  Suprisingly this

```
class X {
   mt19937 generator;
   uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution;
   decltype(bind(distribution, generator)) dice;
};
```

yields the error `error C2660: 'bind' : function does not take 2 arguments` in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @juanchopanza … which comes at the cost of some overhead.

Comment: Looks like an MSVC bug.

Comment: FYI, `bind` will create copies of its arguments, so if you were to create, say, `dice2`, it would use a different distribution and RNG than `dice`. To avoid this you'll need to wrap the arguments in [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

Comment: What does the standard say about default and/or copy construction of the type returned from `std::bind`? EDIT: 20.8.9.1.2/5 "*Remarks*: The return type shall satisfy the requirements of `MoveConstructible`."

Comment: @chris It is far from obvious. What's the meaning of `distribution` and `generator` inside the `decltype`? To what *entities* do they refer?

Comment: @n.m., I'm not sure what the standard says about it, but Clang compiles it and it's not unreasonable to assume Clang wins when it's up against MSVC.

Comment: @chris OK, found it. It's legal in C++11. Non-static data members may appear in an *unevaluated operand*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always *gasp* write a function instead of using a lambda/bind/etc.:

```
class X {
   mt19937 generator;
   uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution;
public:
   auto dice() -> decltype(distribution(generator)) {
     return distribution(generator);
   }
   // or alternatively
   auto operator() () -> decltype(distribution(generator)) {
     return distribution(generator);
   }
};
```

Bonus points for parameterizing on the type of the generator and/or distribution, and for holding the generator with a `std::shared_ptr` so that you can make several objects with differing distributions that share the same engine. You'll eventually want a constructor to seed the generator as well - Ideally with something like `std::random_device{}()`.

Or, [the answer I think you are looking for](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f6e95f452a24bf):

```
class X {
   mt19937 generator{std::random_device{}()};
   uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution{1,6};
public:
   decltype(bind(std::ref(distribution), std::ref(generator))) dice{
     bind(std::ref(distribution), std::ref(generator))
   };
};
```

I'm sorry I mocked you for trying to use `bind` in the first place: it's actually kind of neat that you can write this class with "no code" in C++11. We need to get type-inference for class member declarations in C++17 so this could be:

```
class X {
   auto generator = mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
   auto distribution = uniform_int_distribution<unsigned>{1,6};
public:
   auto dice = bind(std::ref(distribution), std::ref(generator));
};
```

Given that [the latest Concepts Lite paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf) proposes using concept names anywhere in the language where `auto` can appear to mean "infer type, ill-formed if type doesn't model named concept," `auto` member declarations may not be out of the question.

Comment: But the point of `std::bind` is … *gasp* … to make this unnecessary. (Not that I think this code is a bad solution per se …)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't really think that is the point of bind. The point of bind, as far as I can tell, is to allow one to not have to write one-off functions or functors, separated from their point of usage. It doesn't really fulfill that role in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what the point of `bind` is now that we have lambdas in the language. Generic lambdas in C++14 will only make things worse for poor `bind`. I admit that for this specific case, `bind(distribution, generator)` is more terse than `[this]{return distribution(generator);}`.

Comment: It may save you a few characters there, but I would still prefer the lambda. Lambda's are, in my opinion, much easier to understand than bind, because they take a form similar to normal functions, and we write functions constantly.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Agree completely: `bind` is effectively a mini-DSL that I have to think about instead of simply reading like any other C++ code. Lambda wins out in the end for terseness as well: `bind(std::ref(distribution), std::ref(generator))` vs. `[this]{return distribution(generator);}`.

Comment: @Casey: I used your first solution and it works fine and fast, thanks. The second one (with the std::ref()) gives compiler errors (could not deduce template argument...). From a practical standpoint, my problem is solved.  Great work, guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of `std::bind` is unspecified: this means that you cannot store its raw result without type inference. However, you can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) to encapsulate the result of `bind`:

```
#include <functional>
std::function<unsigned()> dice(std::bind(distribution, generator));
auto result = dice();
```

**EDIT:** As whoever said above, this is most clearly a Visual Studio issue. I can confirm that this compiles with VS2013:

```
#include <functional>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class X {
    mt19937 generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution;
    std::function<unsigned()> dice;

public:
    X() : dice(bind(distribution, generator)) {}

    unsigned roll() { return dice(); }
};
```

but changing the type of `dice` to `decltype(bind(distribution, generator))` makes the whole thing fail with flying colors (even though it still works with clang).

Comment: But `decltype` *is* using type inference, no?

Comment: Apologies, yes. Let me test a bit further then. Note however that Microsoft's implementation of variadic templates was broken and hackish until VS2013, so it could be a bug that `std::function` will almost certainly work around.

Comment: Microsoft's implementation of variadic templates was _nonexistent_ until VC++ 2013. ;-]

Comment: I know, but they had ugly ugly hacks to support several of the methods that would require variadic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[It works on GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e37c2d65d891092). I’m pretty sure that’s just a compiler bug. Unfortunately this means that you have to bite the bitter pill and use one of the workarounds described in the other answers.